# How to get browsers to cache video response from Azure CDN?

Tags: html, caching, video, azure, browser-cache

I have uploaded an mp4 video animation to Azure Blob Storage. The headers are are all default apart from setting the Content-Type to video/mp4. The video can be accessed at http://paddingtondev.blob.core.windows.net/media/1001/animation_default_headers.mp4

I have an Azure CDN sitting over that blob storage account. The URL for the same video through the CDN is http://az593791.vo.msecnd.net/media/1001/animation_default_headers.mp4

When I access the blob-stored video through an HTML5 video element on a web page, the browser (have tested in FF and Chrome) receives the entire video in a 200 HTTP response. Further requests for that video then receive a 304 response from blob storage.

However, when you request the video through the Azure CDN, it helpfully returns it to you as a series of HTTP 206 partial responses. This is in response to the browsers specifying a Range header with the request.

However, further requests for the video through the CDN are NOT cached, and the whole video is re-downloaded by the browser (through a series of further 206 requests).

How do I ensure the video is cached? I understand the usefulness of partial responses, but in our case the video won't be seekable and we only play it when the whole file is downloaded. I can see a few approaches here, but none have helped so far:

1. Forbid Azure CDN from returning partial responses
2. Remove range header from original browser request somehow
3. Persuade browsers to cache 206 partial responses

I have tried adding a max-age Cache-Control header to the file but this had no impact. Ideally we wouldn't even hit Azure at all when re-loading the video (as it will never change), but I'm happy to accept the cost of the HTTP request to Azure if it subsequently returns a 304 .

Comment: +1 for posting an interesting azure question :)

Answer (score 2):

Caching 206 responses is tricky.  The RFC for the client requires that in order to cache the content the ETAG and the range requested must match exactly.

There are a couple of things you can check - 
1) Verify that the ETAGS did not change on the request.  From the description of your environment (and setting the content expiration date), this sounds unlikely, but it may be an avenue to pursue.

2) More likely is that the range requests are not lining up.  A request for byte range 1000-->2000 and a second request of 1500-->2000 would not (per RFC) be served from the client cache.  So you may be in a situation of seeing exactly what is supposed to happen with that particular format/client.

I'm pretty sure HTML5 only supports progressive download, so unless you wanted to reconsider the delivery this may be expected behavior.

Comment: FWIW, I'd like to add that while checking the mp4 url headers using the [REDbot](https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpaddingtondev.blob.core.windows.net%2Fmedia%2F1001%2Fanimation_default_headers.mp4) tool it reported: `The ETag header's syntax isn't valid and doesn't conform to its specified syntax`

Comment: It seems that no matter what I do, I can't get Firefox, Edge, or Chrome to locally cache any 206 responses (haven't tried IE yet). Both the ETAG and range requests line up perfectly, but the responses are never cached. Is there a working example of this anywhere on the internet? My gut seems to be telling me that the browsers just don't support this.